# Should neo4j be very slow on a lot of merge requests?

Tags: performance, neo4j, lucene

I'm experiencing a very slow **neo4j**, **htop** shows it's **lucene** who ate all the CPUs on server.

I'm mostly writing the data, attempting 50-500 **cypher** requests per second, each is like

```
FOREACH (id in {ids} | MERGE (:Community {id: id}))
```

all 3 request generators are here https://github.com/PublicRadio/VK_graph_reflector/tree/master/lib/reflectors (yes, JavaScript ES2015)

I've started to suspect lucene to slow down everything because of MERGE requests, am I right? Can it be the reason?
How can I optimise all that stuff if I'm right?

Comment: Can you share the visual query plan for your query? just prefix it by profile

Comment: also all your active indexes and constraints, with :schema in the browser

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you my friend! I've discovered constraints, and now I'm creating about 30k nodes per minute on my local machine, it's unbelievable! I'll try it on server soon and will check out how it's going on, but it's dramatic performance raise!

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your visual query plan?

Just take the query and prefix it with `PROFILE` in the browser.

I think it's a number of things:

1. use cypher parameters not string substitution
2. try to merge only on single properties that have a constraint (or index)
3. if you don't need to merge use MATCH, i.e. if data already exists !
4. if you don't need unique relationships use CREATE, i.e. when you know that you just need to connect new nodes to existing nodes.

something like this:

```
MATCH (group:VK_Group {id: {group_id} })
MERGE (post:VK_Wall_Post { id: {post_id}}) ON CREATE SET post.date={post_date} 
CREATE UNIQUE (group)-[:Published]-(post)
FOREACH (track IN {tracks} |
    MERGE (trackNode:VK_Track {id: track.id}) 
     ON CREATE SET trackNode.title=track.title, 
                   trackNode.duration=track.duration
    MERGE (artist:Artist {name: track.artist})
    MERGE (trackNode)<-[:Performed]-(artist)
    MERGE (post)-[:Attached]->(trackNode)
)
```

alternatively to be able to use match for the loop:

```
MATCH (group:VK_Group {id: {group_id} })
MERGE (post:VK_Wall_Post { id: {post_id}}) ON CREATE SET post.date={post_date} 
CREATE UNIQUE (group)-[:Published]-(post)
UNWIND {tracks} as track
MERGE (trackNode:VK_Track {id: track.id}) 
       ON CREATE SET trackNode.title=track.title, 
                     trackNode.duration=track.duration
MERGE (artist:Artist {name: track.artist})
MERGE (trackNode)<-[:Performed]-(artist)
MERGE (post)-[:Attached]->(trackNode)
```

Comment: 1, 2. ok, got it

3,4. I really need unique entries and (i think at least) relationships with unique IDs, that's a point

Comment: don't do relationships with unique id's it's usually not needed.